# Displaying dynamic number of objects on an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>my site</title>
        <script>
            // javascript code here
            // generates a random number, X, from 1 to 10 each time this page is requested
            // displays X number of "blue-object" 
        </script>
        <style>
            /*css if needed */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class = "blue-object" style="background:blue; margin:20px">This is an instance of a blue object</div>
        <div class = "blue-object" style="background:blue; margin:20px">This is an instance of a blue object</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So currently the page above is static. It always display 2 objects of the "blue-object" class.
I need to make it dynamic. So for the sake of simplicity, the number these objects that gets displayed is a randomly generated number. So how can that be done?

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - **Please note**, we are not a code-writing service.  
The community is made up of volunteers that give up their free time and share their knowledge.
Please read our [ask] page and [edit] your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>my site</title>

        <style>
          div{
  background-color:blue;
    margin:20px;
}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="main">
       <script> 
         var desiredText="Hey there! change me ;)";
         //You can just change the variable to your desired text and that's it :)
 var randomRepeater=function(desiredText){
  var iterator=Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
   console.log("will create "+iterator+" divs this time :) ");
  for(var i=0;i<iterator;i++){
    var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = desiredText.toString();
    document.getElementById("main").appendChild(div);
  }
           }
 randomRepeater(desiredText);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yepp , you're welcome!